# how to keep httprequest in sequence using multiple instances of web role

Tags: azure

We have a public facing rest api and just started to move it to the Azure. The architecture now is using the command pattern: the web api encapsulates the http request to a message queue, and then another app handles the message. The most important thing is that the http requests must be handled in order of submissions. 
My questions is how to take the advantages of the scalability in Azure. If I use a web role hosting the web api and turn on multiple instances of the web role for high performance, how can I make sure that the multiple instances will put the requests in the queue storage (or service bus or table storage) in the order of their submissions?

Comment: Do you use any custom code to synchronize web requests (make them sequential) in your current API?

Comment: No the rest api is stateless. first in first handled, then put in the queue. Should I use some synchronize mechanism for the httprequests in my api controls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't user any custom sync mechanism at the moment, then it should not be any difference whether the API is running in one instance or many. The only thing you need to do is to use Service Bus queue which ensures [FIFO behavior](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh767287.aspx) for brokered messages. In this case the first message that hits the queue will be handler first, and so on.

If you are thinking of using some sync mechanism for http requests in REST API, then you will lose scalability and performance, since all requests will become synchronous, and no matter how many role instances do you have, only one request is processed at a time. Hope this gives you some food for thoughts.